# Exportar Celda "FECHA" de un DatagridView a PDF

Tags: c#

He estado batallando al exportar un `DataGridView` ya que la columna fecha la exporta con todo y la hora. Utilizo `iTextSharp` para exportar la tabla. la pregunta es:
¿Como puedo exportar los datos de la columna fecha pero sin la hora.

Asi es como lo exporta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero que se exporte sin la Hora. Ayuda por favor...

Este es el codigo que tengo para exportar:

> 

```
Document doc1 = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10f,
> 10f, 10f, 0f);
>             PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, new FileStream(@"C:\Users\dany_\Desktop\Estado_Cuenta.pdf",
> FileMode.Create));
>             doc1.Open();  PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(optendatos.Columns.Count);
>             for (int j = 0; j < optendatos.Columns.Count; j++)
>             {
>                 table.AddCell(new Phrase(optendatos.Columns[j].HeaderText));
>                 table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
>             }
>             table.HeaderRows = 1;
>             for (int i = 0; i < optendatos.Rows.Count; i++)
>             {
>                 for (int k = 0; k < optendatos.Columns.Count; k++)
>                 {
>                     if (optendatos[k, i].Value != null)
>                     {
>                         table.AddCell(new Phrase(optendatos[k, i].Value.ToString()));
>                     }
>                     else
>                     {
>                         table.AddCell("");
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>             doc1.Add(table);
>             doc1.Add(new Paragraph(" "));
              doc1.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código seria el siguiente:

```
((DateTime)datagfridview.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")),
```

Ya solo adaptarlo a tu código.